# Determine lock owner in Informix

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, informix

I have an asp.net application that in some circumstances will return a lock error during a query. This is fine, but what I would like to be able to do is log the owner of the lock in order to track possible behavioral issues (people opening an application in update mode and then leaving it that way for an extensive time period.)

Is there a way to have the Informix error report the owner of the lock in addition to the table (which is what it returns now)? I did see [Check if table is locked in Informix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471182/check-if-table-is-locked-in-informix) which tells how to query the syslocks view for a list of locks, but that can be an extensive list and I only want to log the owner of the specific lock that I ran into with my failed query.

I'm using Informix 10.0, if the version makes a difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for including the version of Informix.  The main difference it makes here is that "Informix 10.00 is out of support" so any problem won't be fixed in this version (nor in 11.10 because that's out of support too, and it would be unlikely to be fixed in 11.50 because that is no longer being marketed so you'd be expected to upgrade to at least 11.70).

Comment: Well, yes, I knew it was out of date; that didn't mean there wasn't a way to do it that I simply wasn't aware of, however. Unfortunately I don't see my company upgrading to 11.70 any time soon, so even if that did have this functionality, it wouldn't do me any good. Thanks for the answer, however. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there isn't a way to make Informix report who owns the lock that your session ran into.  It is not provided as standard, and there's no way to alter that.